# Creating a gradient thaf follows the arch of my shape in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient

I thought what I wanted was quite simple but it appears not to be. I am trying to create a power meter but I can't get my gradient to to match my shape. I added a link below as to what I have and what I want. I heard you could do what I wanted in illustrator but since I don't have that program I'm limited to the abilities of Photoshop.

Idea of what I want:
https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/39301/screenshots/407295/accuracy_meter.png

What I have:
[image]

You can see that the gradient lines are straight when I want them to follow the curve of my shape

Can I make a meter like that in Photoshop.

Comment: I do not know what a "mlb power meter" is, and the link tells me nothing. Please edit your question and give us more information, prefeably screenshots of what you have tried and where it goes wrong.

Comment: Use Illustrator if at all possible. It has a 'gradient along a path' option that exactly does what you want it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok.

1. Create any shape you want
2. Right click on the shape layer and convert it into a **Smart Object**
3. Double click on the converted layer

[image]

4. It will open a new window to your shape where you can

   a) double click the shape and give it a gradient in styles

   b) create new layer (**⌘+⇧+N**) and add gradient with the gradient tool (press G)

   c) you can add a gradient layer (**Layer>New Fill Layer>Gradient..**)
5. Press Save (**⌘+S**) and later  close the window (**⌘+W**).
6. You will be brought back to your original window, select your **Smart object**, press (**⌘+T**) to transform
7. Switch between free transform and wrap modes
8. Select your wrap shape and press (**⌘+Enter**)

Now you will see the gradient follows the actual shape form rather staying at static style.

You can always double click on the smart object layer you've created and edit the gradient without loosing quality.

```
I chose option **c)** because while i was recording it was the fastest way to perform :]
```

Enjoy

[image]

[image]

Comment: No idea why I didn't convert to smart object  ...I'll just delete my answer :)

Comment: hehe @CAI i saw your answer and it caught my interest,  the only thing was missing was smart object yes.

Comment: Yeh can't believe I missed that. Oh well :)

Comment: holy crap thank you so much!!! That did it! I will just keep this in my back pocket now!

Comment: No worries @BabyCoder , always here to help :]

Answer (score 0):

Have a go at this and see if it works, good luck.[image: photoshop gradient]

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure you could do this, at least if I interpreted your question right.
I think you get (close to) the result you want with the free transform tool:

https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/free-transformations-images-shapes-paths.html

**Let me further explain what i mean:**

Step 1 Make a selection with the selection tool. (this could be a rectangle)

Step 2 create a  new layer.

Step 3 Fill the selection with a solid color.

Step 3 Select te shape with again if you unselected it.

Step 4 Fill the shape with a gradient.

Step 5 Press crtl+t or cmd+t. (depends on system)

step 6 Click the free tranform tool and mold it to the shape you want it to be.
[image]

Comment: The shape transforms but the gradient does not

Comment: @Jerry could you elaborate on how you would use the tool? Or perhaps more information about it?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I now included the steps i made. Also I added my (somewhat sloppy) end result

Answer (score -1):

This is my idea. I hope this will help you
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you please post the text as, well, text, so it shows up in search, both locally and in Google? That way others can improve on your answer as well. As-is, it contains some annoying typos. Thanks!

Comment: Didnt undarstand you wich text to post where ?
Im new at stack community :/

Comment: You have text in your image, as an image. Yours is red. We'd like text to be typed text. So please consider spitting up your image in parts and typing the text in between in the answer field, not in your image editor.